# Xamarin Form Project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm getting an error bellow when I run my application in the Android emulator:
Xamarin.form Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Drawable com.companyname.GroupChat:mipmap/icon with resource ID #0x7f030000

That's the Image Code

[image: Screenshot of the same]

Comment: Check if the image exists and it had been set `build action:AndroidResource`.